# How do I get more response until I get the correct solution?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question and waited for an answer for more than 8 hours. I have got one answer, but that answer doesn't resolve my issue. Nobody is responding to my question because it appears somewhere in second or third page.

I know of bounties, but I have to wait for two days before I can set a bounty for my question.

How do I get more responses?

Comment: The [last question you asked](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/how-to-group-fields-with-select-option) was over a month ago (April 22nd), so is eligible for bounty right now. If you haven't needed to revisit that question in over a month I'd say the 2-day waiting period on bounties is incidental. Do you have a link to the question in question, or are you just asking in general?

Comment: I'm asking in general, it will help me in future

Comment: Related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already an answer, you can simply leave a comment to the user who answered, explaining that what proposed as solution is not working for you. It could be that user misunderstood what you were asking, or needs more information to answer the question correctly. In the case you are asked more information, add the information into your question, rather than adding it in a comment for the user. In that way, the question will be bumped to the front page, and more users will notice it.

Keep in mind that editing too much times a post makes it a Community Wiki; if you have to edit your question, makes your edits substantial, and avoid editing it just to make it bump.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not getting appropriate answers, your question isn't good enough `:-)`.

What you should do is to edit your question and supply more details. You may take the opportunity to add material that makes it clear why the answer(s) already provided does not provide a solution.

Editing the question also bumps it back on the *active* page.